# Make a curve have only one horizontal tangent line

Tags: calculus

Find p so that the curve $y = x^3 +2x^2 + px + 3$ has one horizontal tangent line only. 
I know I have to take the first derivative and make it equal zero, but I'm not sure how I should continue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that you first need to find the derivative and set it to zero giving:$$3x^2+4x+p=0\tag{1}$$The question says that find $p$ such that there is only **one** horizontal tangent. So you need to find $p$ such that $(1)$ has only a single solution for $x$ - i.e. both roots of this quadratic are identical.

**HINT**: Make use of the properties of the discriminant of a qudratic equation.

Comment: So for the equation to have only one solution, I need to have the discriminant D be zero? I guess I'm not as dumb as I thought.

Comment: Yes - Correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You shall derivate first then try to find the condition that assures that the equation has only one single root, i.e to put $b^2$-$4$$a$$c$ = 0 ($c$=$p$) so that there exists only one minima or maxima i.e only 1 horizontal tangent line for the function shall be obtained ! and hence you find $p$!